# Where do i view an existing API gateway key in AWS management console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am currently working on an existing AWS API gateway setup by another 3rd party team who has left the project. Currently i am maintaining the existing APIs and need some help in finding out the API keys that is used for an API. I tried finding out in the AWS console and no luck.

Can someone please help here? THanks in advance.

Tried using the command in CLI - get-api-keys, but only some of the APIs had keys while the others turned nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, found it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In API Gateway go to "Usage Plans" and find the Usage Plan with your associated API stage. In the worst case you have to click through many of them...

If you have found the correct usage plan click on the "API Keys" Tab. All listed API Keys are valid for your API Gateway Stage.

Click on one of the API Keys, then you can click "Show" to display the key.